# jQuery .load: any way to load the same page when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a website that loads pages to a container div:

```
function goto(addr) {
    $("#content").load(addr);
}
```

and a link that executes it

```
<a href="#" id="aboutus" onclick="goto('page/aboutus.php');">About us</a>
```

My problem is that whenever the page is refreshed, the loaded content resets to the default page (page/home.php). How could I do so that it loads the previous displayed page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use local storage for example or sessions.
Local storage example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var lastPage = localStorage['lastPage'];
    if (!lastPage) { // If user was on any url before we will exectue goto function
        goto(lastPage)
    }

    function goto(addr) {
         localStorage['lastPage'] = addr; // Set url to local storage before load page
         $("#content").load(addr);
    }

});
```

Comment: What if I open the site in an other tab, click on a link on the first one and refresh the page on the other? Use sessionStorage instead as **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**

Answer (score 0):

not only localStore but you need change the hash of url, and after do one function to catch hash code and execute at you "goto" function...

"something like that"

```
function hashnav(){
   var hashfull = document.location.hash
   var hash = hashfull.replace('#', '');
   var $page = '';
   goto(hash);
}
function changeHash($hash) {
   window.location.hash = $hash;
}

function goto(addr) {
   changeHash(addr);
}

$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function() {
   hashnav();
   return false;
});
```